# How to determine active tab in jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm trying to control what is shown on a tab's page with a php value. My basic code is shown below. The tabs work correctly as far as switching is concerned. But the tab code doesn't control the php code so instead of the contents of one tab showing, they all show. Is there a way to control what is shown using php like this?

```
    <div id="handle-tabs" style="overflow: auto;">
      <ul>
        <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section-one">Section One</a>'; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section-two">Section Two</a>'; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section-three">Section Three</a>'; ?></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="section-one"> 
          <?php 
          $this_group = 'one';
          DoSomething(1);
          ?> 
      </div>

      <div id="section-two"> 
          <?php 
          $this_group = 'two';
          DoSomething(2);
          ?> 
      </div>

      <div id="section-three">   
          <?php 
          $this_group = 'three';
          DoSomething(3);
          ?>  
      </div>    
    </div>

    function DoSomething($id) {
      switch ($id) {
       case 1: echo 'one'; break; 
       case 2: echo 'two'; break;
       case 3: echo 'three'; break;
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to check the "current" tab, by watching the `$_GET` variable that you are passing.

I've modified it a bit from what you had originally, to make it somewhat simpler.

Then, in the `DoSomething` function, I've shown you how to "watch" for the current tab, and NOT output anything if it's not the one being rendered.

```
<div id="handle-tabs" style="overflow: auto;">
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section=1">Section One</a>'; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section=2">Section Two</a>'; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo '<a href="example.com?section=3">Section Three</a>'; ?></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="section-one"> 
      <?php 
      $this_group = 'one';
      DoSomething(1);
      ?> 
  </div>

  <div id="section-two"> 
      <?php 
      $this_group = 'two';
      DoSomething(2);
      ?> 
  </div>

  <div id="section-three">   
      <?php 
      $this_group = 'three';
      DoSomething(3);
      ?>  
  </div>    
</div>

function DoSomething( $id ) {
  // load the current tab ID into the $current variable
  $current = (int)( isset( $_GET['section'] ) ) ? $_GET['section'] : '';

  // if the tab to be displayed is not the "current" one, then do NOT render anything
  if ( $id != $current ) {
      return;
  }

  switch ( $id ) {
   case 1: 
       echo 'one'; 
       break; 
   case 2: 
       echo 'two'; 
       break;
   case 3: 
       echo 'three'; 
       break;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The tab switching is handled with jquery so the page is never reloaded, which means there GET doesn't change. Are you saying I need to force a reload for each tab click?

Comment: It would seem your question is mislabeled / unclear then, yes? You ask for PHP, and you tagged the question PHP, but didn't mention jQuery anywhere at all.  Why don't you edit the question and make it clear, and include your _jQuery_ code instead of your PHP.  (Additionally, on a javascript question, please include the rendered HTML, not the PHP to create the HTML)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion I caused. I assumed jquery was implied but should have mentioned it. But showing the source won't make a difference since php is involved. But your response made me look for other options and I think what I need to do is use ajax to set the variable. I will give that a try. I do appreciate your responses.